# I get "The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system" when executing the program

Tags: c++, qt5

I have this code:

```
    int a = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> inputs;
    QString str = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    qDebug()<<str;
    std::string input = str.toStdString();
    int l = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i<l; i++){

        if(input[i] == '\n'){
            i+=1;
            qDebug()<<i;
        }
        else{
            //int a = 0;
            std::string input1;
            while(input[i] != '\n'){
           input1[a] = (char)input[i];
           i++;
           a++;
            }
            inputs.push_back(input1);
        }

    }

   std::string b = inputs[0];
   QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(b);
   qDebug()<<qstr;
```

When trying to run it, the application exits with this error:
`The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system`.

Another unexpected fact is that at debugging `int a = 6432`, `int i = 6441` and strings input, inpu1, b are not accessible. Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks wrong

```
//int a = 0;
std::string input1;
while(input[i] != '\n'){
  input1[a] = (char)input[i];
  i++;
  a++;
}
```

(untested code) this should remove at least one of the problems namely that you index input1 out of bounds.

```
std::string input1;
while(input[i] != '\n'){
  input1.push_back((char)input[i]);
  i++;
}
```